# Tensorflow vs Tensorflow Lite for mobile apps ML data pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, mobile, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I want to build a ML data pipeline for a recommender system in a dating mobile app.

Currently, I am in a very early stage trying to figure out the infrastructure but I am confused with tensorflow and tensorflow lite.

Can I build the system using tensorflow and then after training, hyperparameter tuning etc. deploy the model in backend?

Is it mandatory to use tensorfow lite whenever wanting to use ML for mobile or that is used only when you actually want to train the model in a phone device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow Lite is mainly for inference use cases. After training TF models in the desktop/server side, you can convert the trained TF model to the corresponding TensorFlow Lite model to deploy them to mobile with some techniques, for example, quantizations.